# heatmapGridSeries overlay over line chart

Tags: lightningchart

I came Across heatmapGridSeries in lightning chart , I just want to know if this is possible.

[image]

Please Check above image , I have lineseries with one axis.. and i want this color bands above the line series with opacity.

For example

if I add value to the heatmapGridSeries from 0 to 100 , it should automatically show orange.. from 100 to 200 it should show green and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done, but shouldn't be a very practical usage case for heatmaps.

Paletted/gradient series background or bands should give nicer results.

Here's a snippet that looks like your picture (without the line series), and also adds a single Band so you can see how they behave a bit differently.

Transparency can be added after R,G,B.

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  LUT,
  PalettedFill,
  ColorRGBA,
  emptyLine,
  SolidFill,
  AxisScrollStrategies,
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
const line = chart.addLineSeries()
const heatmap = chart.addHeatmapScrollingGridSeries({
  scrollDimension: 'columns',
  resolution: 1,
  step: {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
  },
})
const transparency = 100
heatmap
  .setFillStyle(new PalettedFill({
    lut: new LUT({
      steps: [
        {value: 0, color: ColorRGBA(255,127,39, transparency)},
        {value: 1, color: ColorRGBA(181,230,29, transparency)},
        {value: 2, color: ColorRGBA(112,146,190, transparency)},
        {value: 3, color: ColorRGBA(255,242,0, transparency)},
        {value: 4, color: ColorRGBA(237,28,36, transparency)}
      ]
    })
  }))
  .setPixelInterpolationMode('disabled')
  .setWireframeStyle(emptyLine)
  
  
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setInterval(-10, 0).setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
line.add({x:0,y:0})
let x = 1
setInterval(() => {
  const y = Math.random()
  const p = {x, y}
  line.add(p)
  const iColor = x % 5
  heatmap.addIntensityValues([[iColor]])
  x += 1
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi , there is no add function ? my chart is dynamic Live line chart ,  I want to generate this background on the fly based on the x axis value of the line chart.For this which series do u recommend ?

Comment: So, the line chart has data coming in constantly and scrolling on x axis?
How about the background colors, do they move with the line or stay still?

Comment: background color moves with the lines..I think vertical bands will suit me.. what do you say ? any other way apart from bands ??

Comment: I thought of addHeatmapGridSeries because , only by adding values to the series it will automatically generate background for me ,, but for bands i need to keep on creating 100's of bands with different colors.

Comment: It's not an every day usage case so I don't have strong opinions hehe.
I updated the code snippet to use heatmap scrolling grid series, which lets you append values in scrolling manner. If you want it like in your example picture where color only changes every 10 line values, then you should set heatmap step x to 10 and only add intensity value for every 10 line values. How's this?

Comment: So whenever i change color with addIntensityValues , it keeps the same color until i change  again right ? This is perfect , hope it wont slow down ... is there any optimisation to do , I can delete the older one outside the view.. like setmaxpointcount ?

Comment: Heatmap Grid Series is optimized really well. It can handle even millions of data points per second even on weaker devices like laptops, so I don't think you'll be easily running into performance issues.
For configuring data cleaning you can see https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/heatmapscrollinggridseriesintensityvalues.html#setdatacleaning

Comment: For some reason I am not able to use it for my real case scenario ..please check this example I created https://codepen.io/adjmpw/pen/bGRBEOx .. what i need is background should be blank initially , once i click Start Red   button...it should keep on displaying red bg from the last X value of line series. . until i click another button.. hard to explain.. please check the example i created.thanks alot for your support.

Comment: I did some modifications on your codepen which I think is more into the direction you're going for https://codepen.io/adjmpw/pen/bGRBEOx

Comment: I think you had some typos with target2 and target3 in HTML and JS. Additionally I set value: 0 to transparent color. By default all heatmap cells have value 0 so this will give the effect of by default everything being blank

Comment: Hi , i think u pasted same codepen link as mine.. did u meant to send any other link ?

Comment: hi , I was looking it to add to that last X value of line series.. after few minutes.. if i click start red or green.. its trying to fill from very old.. any way to link it to the x value of line series.

For example.. Initially blank.. after few seconds if i click red it should add from last X value of line series.. its adding from beginning.

Comment: Heatmap Scrolling Grid series is ordered, so you'll have to fill the gaps with values matching transparent colors.

Comment: thanks , lineseries and heatseries must share same y axis ?

Comment: Both series can be attached to any axis, doesn't have to be same one.

Comment: hi , how to make heatmap full height .. some series range from 1  to 10.. some range from 10 to 1000

Comment: In this case the heatmap has 1 row (cells along Y axis), each cell height is 1 (step.y value). To make heatmap height 1000 set step.y to 1000.

Comment: I tried it , there is gap in top .. if i do -40 its filling on top..

Comment: Going further you might want to post a new question with updated goal. Managing this in comments does not seem practical anymore.

Comment: sure will create new question

Comment: I just posted new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69117696/full-height-in-heatmapscrollinggridseries