# Full Height in heatmapScrollingGridSeries

Tags: lightningchart

Hi I want full height in heatmapScrollingGridSeries ,

[image]

See the padding on Top , but my line series is covering my full height properly.I tried default Y axis , and even am trying to attach some seperate Y axis to heatmapScrollingGridSeries , but I dont think it uses it. There is always some kind of padding on top of series.

```
  heatmap = chart.addHeatmapScrollingGridSeries({
    scrollDimension: "columns",
    resolution: 1,
    yAxis: customYaxis,
    step: { x: 1, y:1000 },
  });
```

Comment: LightningChart JS v3.2.0 was released yesterday and contains a fix to this issue.

Comment: Thanks , in changelog I saw - - Community version no longer has performance penalty... what does this mean ?

Comment: Community version (not using commercial license key) previously had slightly worse performance compared to when using a license key. We have removed the reason for this slight performance difference and now community users can enjoy the full performance of LightningChart JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered a bug with current version v.3.1 that might be the cause of your trouble.

It seems that specifically `HeatmapScrollingGridSeries` can't be attached to any other Axis than chart default axis.

We'll be fixing this for next version v.3.2.

Meanwhile, maybe you can test your usage case by attaching the line series to the other Y axis, and keeping heatmap series on default Y axis.

Comment: ok thanks.. can we see any roadmap .. arction.com roadmaps are not updated anymore.

Comment: Also please let me know if its possible to add X axis value while doing addIntensityValues ? It would be great if we can insert data in the X  rather than beginning.. it will really useful.

Comment: Heatmap grid series is designed for static X and Y step between data points. Only intensity data is supplied in.
Roadmap at arction.com should be updated in some weeks to come, hopefully for next year or so this time.